# Jquery for slide change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-cycle

My jquery code is like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slideshow").css("overflow","hidden");
    $("ul#slides").cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    pause: 1,
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next'
});
```

And  i want to know ,is there any slide change event in jquery for this...i mean i need to get the slide number when each slide changes

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about Cycle specifically, not general jQuery. The documentation on options for Cycle can be found [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html).

It looks like there is an event called `onPrevNextEvent`:

```
onPrevNextEvent: null,// callback fn for prev/next events: function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement)
```

The second parameter passed into a function you define for that event will be `zeroBasedSlideIndex`. That's your current slide number, with the first slide starting at 0.

So your code might look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slideshow").css("overflow","hidden");
    $("ul#slides").cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    pause: 1,
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next',
    onPrevNextEvent: function(isNext, slideNum) {
        alert("This is slide "+ slideNum);
    }
});
```

Comment: This only gets fired when the user manually clicks the next or prev buttons. Use the before and after options if you also want the event when auto transition occurs.